# Trouble reading a local .txt file to display its contents in webpage

Tags: dart

I want access to each individual line of the specific file to display its stats on a webpage. What steps or code should I use to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the lines of the file in sequence you can use the following code snippet:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  new File("path/to/file").openRead()
    .transform(new StringDecoder())
    .transform(new LineTransformer())
    .listen(print);  // Replace 'print' with your action.
}
```

If you need random access you should have a look at [File.open](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/File.html#open)

For creating a webserver have a look [here](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/io/#writing-web-servers)